# In MySqlConnection.php line 65: Class 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver' not found in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu

I tried every solution related to this error on stack overflow, but nothing work for me. for instance,

- upgrading or downgrading version of "doctrine/dbal" in "require" in composer.json file didn't work
- composer install or update didn't work
- removing onchange() didn't work
- composer require doctrine/dbal didn't work

can anybody provide valid or workable solution? i am just badly stuck here and exhaust with these unrealistic provided solutions :(

Comment: How odd, it should have a slash between PDO and MySQL, at least according to my installation of 8. What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Please share more details, like the code triggering the problem and your attempts to resolve it

Comment: Check you are using the most recent version of doctrine.

Comment: Can you please provide the exact version of Laravel, and the exact version of dbal that you're using? You can get the exact version of Laravel with `php artisan --version`, and the version of `doctrine/dbal` would be in your composer.lock. Look for where it has name/version on separate lines, not in a require block

Comment: Laravel Framework 5.4.36

Comment: Laravel Framework 5.4.36, but i installed php v3.3.33. Also i am using mysql workbench. The error screenshot is attached with this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wWTtv6YOv9DuFoASwB0lNSArzPVdlE9O/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Also it is popping the error on writing "php artisan serve" on the terminal. Error screenshot is attached with this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_l8ocQZZpN-YpV434LGORM9wPd-6dkis/view?usp=sharing

Comment: "name": "doctrine/dbal","version": "3.3.0",

Comment: @aynber when i downgrade doctrine/dbal version by using composer require doctrine/dbal:"2.3" then error message will be In SchemaException.php line 60: There is no column with name 'nick_name_id' on table 'nick_name'.

Comment: "Laravel Framework 5.4.36, but i installed php v3.3.33" - that sounds weird. That version of Laravel is horribly outdated (released more than four years ago!), and that version of PHP isn't even compatible with Laravel. Also, please add all clarification to your question by editing it